# Javascript map within filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, mapping

I am trying to add a property (score) to my units array. `Scores` is an array of object that contains a common id with units.

```
 this.units.map(unit => {
              unit.score = scores
              .filter(score => unit.id === score.unit_id);
 });
```

The objects that are contained in the array.

```
 scores
    {
      unit_id: 1234,
      score: 12,
    }


 this.units
  [
    {
      id: 1234,
      type: 'maths',

    }
   {
      id: '5678',
      type: 'maths',

    }
  ]
```

It looks ok. Is it because unit.id is not available in the filter?

Comment: Now you have edited the code in your question so it works, so what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after. Score does not have a unit_id property, only id.

```js
var scores = [{
  unit_id: 1234,
  score: 12,
}];
var units = [{
  id: 1234,
  type: 'maths',
}, {
  id: 5678,
  type: 'maths',
}];

units.map(unit => {
  unit.score = scores
    .filter(score => unit.id === score.unit_id);
});

console.log(units);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was almost there I think I just went round in circles a bit.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.map` for this, because it doesn't return any value. Use `.forEach` instead.